# Unwanted thin black line on status bar XCODE 9.2 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, statusbar, xcode9.2

[image: Screenshot: Thin Blach line just above status bar]

I'm using Xcode 9.2 and getting this unwanted black line just above the status bar. I have tested it on simulator as well as on devices but getting the same issue. It is not happening with all the screens but with only few of them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like  your view is not expanding all the way. Are you using Autolayout?